# Bean property is not readable or has an invalid getter method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

So, I have a task to write a simple web-application for registry routes. Using Spring MVC. So I have class "Route", where I want to keep start point, finish point and list of intermediate points. But I don't understand, how to put values to list from jsp (e.g. using jstl). So I decide to parse a string.

```
public class Route {
    private String start;
    private String finish;
    private String form;
    private List<String> list;

    public Route() {
    }

    public Route(String start, String finish, String route) {
        this.start = start;
        this.finish = finish;
        this.form = route;
        this.toList();
    }

    public Route(String start, String finish) {
        this.start = start;
        this.finish = finish;
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addTown(String town){
        list.add(town);
    }

    public String getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(String start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public String getFinish() {
        return finish;
    }

    public void setFinish(String finish) {
        this.finish = finish;
    }

    public List<String> getRoute() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setFormRoute(String route) {
        this.form = route; 
        this.toList();
    }    

    private void toList()
    {
        String[] temp = form.split(",");
        for(String temp1 : temp) {
            list.add(temp1);
        }
    }
}
```

and follow JSP:

```
<h2><a href="find.htm">Найти существующий маршрут</a><br/><br/>
    Добавить маршрут</h2>
<h3> 
    <spring:nestedPath path="route">
        <form modelAttribute="routeAttribute" method="POST" action="${add}">
            Пункт отправления:
            <spring:bind path="start">
                <input type="text" name="${status.expression}" value="${status.value}">
            </spring:bind><br/><br/>                    
            Пункт прибытия:
            <spring:bind path="finish">
                <input type="text" name="${status.expression}" value="${status.value}">
            </spring:bind><br/><br/>
            Промежуточные пункты (через запятую):
            <spring:bind path="form">
                <input type="text" name="${status.expression}" value="${status.value}">
            </spring:bind><br/><br/>

            <input type="submit" value="Сохранить">
        </form>
    </spring:nestedPath>
```

If it's nessesary I can post Controller code.
And I have an error:

```
Bean property 'form' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

Can anyone, please, to explain what I do principaly wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the form's getter method to the bean as indicated by the error message

```
public String getForm() {
   return form;
}
```

`setForm` should have a corresponding method

```
public void setForm(String form) {
   this.form = form;
}
```

Comment: both getter and setter should be added. There is already "setFormRoute" which might be a setter, but in that case it should be renamed to setForm(String form).

Comment: `setFormRoute` should probably be split up into 2 separate new methods `setForm` and `setRoute`

Answer (score 2):

add following

```
public String getForm(){
    return form;
}

public void setForm(String form){
    this.form = form;
    this.toList();
}
```