# HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page il select form:form

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

Hy, sorry for my englis not very good, i'm working with spring mvc rom 1 week and 
I would load a list of object to select form and capture the result of select List.
Controller class this is:

```
@Controller
 public class LoginLRI_Controller {

@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String login(Model model) {
    Utente utente = new Utente();
    model.addAttribute("utenteLogin", utente);
    return "Lri";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView loginController(@Valid @ModelAttribute("utenteLogin") Utente utente, BindingResult errors,
        Model model) {
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        return new ModelAndView("Lri");
    } else {
        Collection<Organizzazioni> listOrganizzation = new ArrayList<Organizzazioni>();
        ConnectToDatabase c = new ConnectToDatabase();
        Query query = new Query();
        Boolean loginResp = query.login(utente.getUsername(), utente.getPassword());
        if (loginResp) {
            System.out.println("login riuscito : " + loginResp);

            listOrganizzation = query.loadOrganizzation(utente.getUsername());
            model.addAttribute("listOrganizzation", listOrganizzation);
            Organizzazioni organizzationCom = new Organizzazioni();
            model.addAttribute("organizzationCom", organizzationCom);
            return new ModelAndView("Organizzation");
        } else {
            System.out.println("login non riuscito : " + loginResp);
            return new ModelAndView("Lri");
        }

    }
}
```

Class Organizzazioni this is:

```
public class Organizzazioni {

private int id_organizzazione;
private String nome_organizzazione;

public int getId_organizzazione() {
    return id_organizzazione;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return nome_organizzazione;
}

public void setId_organizzazione(int id_organizzazione) {
    this.id_organizzazione = id_organizzazione;
}

public String getNome_organizzazione() {
    return nome_organizzazione;
}

public void setNome_organizzazione(String nome_organizzazione) {
    this.nome_organizzazione = nome_organizzazione;
}
```

and this is my page Organizzation.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Inserire Organizzazione</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form commandName="organizzationCom" action="" method="POST">
    <form:select path="listOrganizzation" >
        <form:option value="-" label="--SELECT--"></form:option>
    <form:options items="${listOrganizzation}" itemValue="Organizzazioni"/>

        </form:select>
        <input type="submit" value="Salva">
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

when compile I can't resolve this proble,: error is:

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/Organizzation.jsp at line 16
 The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/Organizzation.jsp at line 16

13: </head>
14: <body>
15:     <form:form commandName="organizzationCom" action="" method="POST">
16:         <form:select path="listOrganizzation" >
17:             <form:option value="-" label="--SELECT--"></form:option>
18:             <form:options items="${listOrganizzation}"/>
19:         </form:select>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
```

please anyone can help me? i'm stopped from 4 hours, im' not very good to spring but i need to work and i'm blocked

Comment: try removing this <form:option value="-" label="--SELECT--"> and check once dashes may create problem.

Comment: removed, but the problem not change

Comment: it's a full page :)

Comment: close meta tag and check once.

Comment: where this meta tag that i have to closed?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> to <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>

Comment: removed, :( the jsp page compile only i remove form:select

Answer (score 0):

Try updating options tag like this :

```
<form:options items="${listOrganizzation}" itemValue="Organizzazioni" itemLabel="Organizzazioni"/>
```

Comment: nada, this error:'listOrganizzation' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Comment: add getter setter for 'listOrganizzation' like here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784836/bean-property-is-not-readable-or-has-an-invalid-getter-method

Comment: private ArrayList<Organizzazioni> list;

 public ArrayList<Organizzazioni> getList() {
  return list;
 }

 public void setList(ArrayList<Organizzazioni> list) {
  this.list = list;
 }, the error : HTTP Status 500 - org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'listOrganizzation' of bean class [com.lorussoImpianti.moduloWeb.model.Organizzazioni]: Bean property 'listOrganizzation' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?